# Is it possible to use placeholders on <input type="submit">?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm currently working on at the displaying of information from a database. I was making a summary site where you can only see the important things of a table. After that i made the first element as an `<input type="submit">` in a `<form>`, so u can click it and come to the detail site. My problem is now: The value of this input type has to be my ID, so i can query correctly on me detail site. I was wondering if it is possible to use something like a placeholder, so that the ID is the value, but on the input type is written other text.

My input:

```
<form method="post" action="Details.php">                                                   
    <input type="submit" placeholder = "test" name="Overview" onclick="parent.location='Details.php'" value="<?php echo $data[$i1]; ?>"> 
</form>
```

How it currently looks

[image: How it currently looks]

I want it that the input type still has the same value, but is displaying on the website something else like "test".

Greetings!

Comment: "_so u can click it and come to the detail site_" Why not just use a simple link to the detail page? `<a href="Details.php?id=12">View Details</a>`

Comment: Because i need the ID as value to know for which column i can query for on the detail site. As example: You can see on the image above i have 4 inputs in my table. When i click on the button, only the row with the ID as value behind the button should come.

Comment: Ok, but you get the ID for every row, so adjust that link. `<a href="Details.php?id=<?php echo $data[$i1]; ?>">View Details</a>`. You "simply" want to link to a different page, in my opinion a GET request using `<a>` is more appropriate than a POST form. Glad it works though.

Comment: To be honest, I never worked with GET and always used POST bc I'm new in Website development. Will try it the next time I use it ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but [buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) can have different values and labels.

```
<button name="foo" value="bar">baz</button>
```

Comment: OP probably needs to add `type="submit"` as well, so all buttons will act as submit buttons instead of just the first one (assuming that there's a form around all the buttons as opposed to each button being in a form of its own)

Comment: @ConstantinGroß — No. The **default** `type` is `submit` for a `button` element.

Comment: Strange... Just tried it out and you're right of course! I was always under the assumption that only the first button acts as a submit when none is specifically set as submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a form-tag per row, you can add a hidden input-field in the form and set the value of the submit-button to whatever you like.

```
<form method="post" action="Details.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data[$i1]; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="Overview" value="test" />
</form>
```